# Thread object run method

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to write a program that uses multiple threads. I need to use the run() method after creating my thread objects. This run method seems to be built in. However, I need to write it and I need it to run a loop every time it is called. Can anyone help me understand how to do this?

Comment: Please edit your post to show us what you have written so far?  What research have you done?

Comment: You really need to start from here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: Please read the java tutorial about concurrency: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: @Nambari how about a link to up-to-date JavaDocs? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: Yes I have done research, and I need help, that is why I am here. No it is not homework, its a project I am working on. I haven't written any code yet except declaring variables. I am just trying to understand how I can write the run method when it seems to be built in to the thread object.

Comment: @MattBall It is not like there has been plenty of relevant changes there since Java5 :-) It is a pitty Oracle doesn't have versionless aliases which will always take you to the latest one.

Comment: Ok, but what is your program supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new `Thread` instance by passing an anonymous implementation of the `Runnable` interface and then use the `start()` method to start the thread execution. See below:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    while (!stopped) {
      // do something interesting here
    }
  }
});
t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

Counting Semaphores
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html#counting

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely normal that the `run()` method is built into the `Thread` class. This class is meant to provide basic infrastructure for any class in your application that will represent a thread of execution. Think of `Thread` as 'any thread in the world'. Now the right way to use it in your application is to provide your own class that *inherits* `Thread`. This is done using `extends` keyword or using an anonymous class, like in Dan's answer. Let's assume you have extended the `Thread` class and called your class `TaskToRunInParallel`.

The documentation says that `Thread` class is special -- if you inherit it (like we just did) and put some code in the `run()` method of your own class (`TaskToRunInParallel` in our case), this code will be executed in parallel to the rest of the application. All you need to do is to call `start()` on the object of the class `TaskToRunInParallel`.

This is why the `run()` method is built-in: it provides you a prototype method to override in your own classes. This way any piece of code that works with `Thread` objects will be able to work with your `TaskToRunInParallel` objects, or any other class that inherits from `Thread`. Really: it is guaranteed that all of them will have `run()` method inherited from `Thread` and it's safe for that piece of code to call it. The result of this invocation will always be different though: each class inheriting from `Thread` may override `run()` in its own way. This is called *polymorphism* and together with inheritance is one of the cornerstones of object-oriented programming.

It's surprising how many concepts are involved when you think about overriding `run()` method of `Thread` class. Good luck.